# Display data into dropdown using JSON payload data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this JSON returned from the server:

```
[
   {
      "symbol":"one option"
   },
   {
      "symbol":"second option"
   }
   .......
]
```

Service to get the data:

```
        useEffect(() => {
                const requestOptions = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                };
        
                fetch('/data', requestOptions)
                    .then((response) => {
                        if (response.status !== 200) {
                            throw new Error(response.status);
                        } else {
                            return response.json();
                        }
                    })
                    .then(
                        (futurePairs) => {
                            console.log(futurePairs)
                            props.onSetAvailableFuturesPairs(futurePairs);
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    );
            }, []);
```

......

```
onSetAvailableFuturesPairs: addAvailableFuturesPair,
```

......

```
        export const ADD_AVAILABLE_FUTURES_PAIR = 'availableFuturesPairs:addAvailableFuturesPairs';
        
        export function addAvailableFuturesPair(newPair) {
            return {
                type: ADD_AVAILABLE_FUTURES_PAIR,
                payload: {
                    newPair: newPair
                }
            }
        }
```

......

```
availableFuturesPairs: [],
```

......

Display data:

```
                        <Select
                            onChange={event => changeSelectedFuturesPair(event.target.value)}
                            value={props.selectedFuturesPair}>
                            {props.availableFuturesPairs.map((option) => (
                                <option key={option.symbol} value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
                            ))}
                        </Select>
```

But I get error:

```
`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try with index to pass into the key prop

```
{props.availableFuturesPairs.map((option) => (
                                <option key={option.symbol} value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
                            ))}
```

**Updated:**

```
{props.availableFuturesPairs.map((option, index) => (
                                <option 
key={index} 
value={option.symbol}
>{option.symbol}</option>
                            ))}
```

Comment: Now I get `Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.`

Comment: @user1285928 try option.symbol || "" and in select tag props.selectedFuturesPair || ""

Answer (score 0):

You can provide index as second parameter to arrow function

```
props.availableFuturesPairs.map((option,index) => (
                                <option key={index} value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
                            ))
```

or install uuidv4

and use it as

```
props.availableFuturesPairs.map((option) => (
                                <option key={uuidv4()} value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
                            ))
```

Comment: Every time a component's key changes React will create a new component instance rather than update the current one, so for performance's sake using uuidv4() will be sub-optimal to say the least.

ref: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

Comment: Now I get `Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.`